# Split a picture into 54 pictures

Tags: pictures, crop

I want to take this:[image: deck of cards]

and make one separate picture for for each card.

Is there a quick / easy / free way to do this?

Comment: I know you can use software such as Adobe Fireworks to split and image into multiple individual ones using guidelines and such. I am curious to know of other methods, though. +1

Comment: @iglvzx Why not put that as an answer?

Comment: Ah. You are correct. I was hoping for a 'free' software solution.

Comment: After some research, it looks like GIMP can accomplish this as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal):

```
convert AtoCb.jpg -crop 11x5@  +repage  +adjoin  card_%d.jpg
```

This creates 55 image tiles based on an 11x5 layout.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for uniformly spaced pieces.

Comment: Yeah, I should have caveated this with if there is any variance in the size of each image tile on the original, then it might go out a bit.  Make sure the dimensions of the original image are factors of 11 and 5 in x and y.

Answer (score 1):

**Adobe Fireworks** has a 'slicing' feature which can export an image into multiple images. As for the opensource realm, **GIMP** has a `Guillotine` feature located under `Image > Transform`. These both use 'guides', vertical and horizontal lines which you have to place beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm handling this right now, using Gimp (for very similar reasons).

*TLDR - drag guides out from the vertical/horizontal rulers till you've got everything outlined, then use Filters > Web > Slice from top menu.*

**1a.** In Gimp I drag from the vertical and horizontal ruler till I've gotten everything outlined.

[image]

**1b.** If your "sprite sheet" has little margins between the sprites that don't want included in the slice, you'll wanna add *extra* margins. This is going to create a bunch of extra sprites you don't want in the end.

[image]

---

**2.** In the top menu select **Filters** > **Web** > **Slice**

[image]

---

**3a.** I suggest you create a folder for these to save in, and point the "Path for HTML export" at it. I don't bother setting the "Separate image folder". You can throw away the generated HTML file, but it's there if you want it.

[image]

**3b.** Click **OK** and *wait*.

---

**4.** When it's done, I like to sort by file size and quickly remove all the extra "margin" sprites that I may have had to make. Sorting this way generally means they're all in a row for easy deletion.

[image]

Cheers